# docker can't push to remote private registry

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to do a push to my remote private registry, but it fails every time.

I can do a pull, no problem.

I logged in to the registry, although I don't think I needed to (didn't for pulls)..

`push` has never worked remotely. All the images in the registry were built and pushed on the same remote machine as the registry.

I've configured an entry on my workstation for the remote registry as insecure.

I can see from the logging in the registry container that I'm communicating, but there are no errors or warnings beyond the `blob unknown` error which is normal for a new repository. Plenty of `msg=info` entries, but nothing informative.

I'm using Docker-Client/17.09.0-ce \(windows\)) on my workstation and docker v1.12.3 on the server. There is a proxy, it doesn't seem to hurt the `pull` though.

How can I work out what the problem is?

Here's the output (with debug on):

`$ docker -D push adam12438.cd2.mc.com:12345/adam-app-proxy
The push refers to a repository [adam12438.cd2.mc.com:12345/adam-app-proxy]
ddac59ff496f: Preparing
dff756936416: Preparing
c54b65edfaea: Preparing
63c39cd4a775: Preparing
350d50e58b6c: Preparing
cec7521cdf36: Preparing
cec7521cdf36: Waiting
c54b65edfaea: Retrying in 5 seconds
[snipped]
63c39cd4a775: Retrying in 1 second
EOF`

Comment: use ` -D` to debug the output and see if it uses the proxy. Also, have you logged in into the registry? Maybe that is needed before a push

Comment: @samthegolden I turned debug on but I can't see any info to tell  if it uses the proxy. In fact, the debug output was exactly the same as the non-debug output. Any advice?